# Select only integers from char column using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I write a select statement to select only integers (and nothing more) from a char column in SQL Server. For example, my table name is POWDER with 2 columns, ID (int) and Name(char (5))

```
ID     Name
-- ----------
1     AXF22
2     HYWWW
3     24680
4     8YUH8
5     96635
```

I want to be able to select only those rows that contain an integer and nothing more (ID 3 and ID 5 in this example)

If I try:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM POWDER
 WHERE Name LIKE '[0-9]%'
```

...it will return:

```
ID     Name
--    ----------
3      24680
4      8YUH8
5      96635
```

Any ideas how to get the rows containing just integers?

Comment: @Andy Select: What RBDMS? MySQL? SQL Server?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM POWDER WHERE IsNumeric(Name) = 1
```

IsNumeric returns 1 for some other characters that are valid in numbers, such as + and - and $ but for your input you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

> SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name LIKE '[0-9]%%'

Answer (score 2):

To avoid issues with ISNUMERIC and all spaces, -, +, . etc, use the fact that the column is char(5)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM POWDER
 WHERE Name LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Edit: for any number of characters. Double negative...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM POWDER
 WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: Hi gbn, thanks for your response.

what happens if I have a Name values that are less than 5 characters?

Answer (score 2):

Use positive and negative checks to make sure we have an integer: It must contain a digit. Only digits and spaces are allowed. No spaces are allowed between digits.

```
SELECT *
  FROM POWDER 
 WHERE Name LIKE '%[0-9]%'
   AND Name NOT LIKE '%[^0-9 ]%'
   AND Name NOT LIKE '%[0-9]% %[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM POWDER   
WHERE Name patindex ('%[a-z]%',name) != 0
```

Comment: How can you use `%` without like in SQL queries?

Comment: we can use in patindex refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276881%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

The last one is the best,kind of works really really well.

```
SELECT *   FROM POWDER   
  WHERE Name LIKE '%[0-9]%'    
       AND Name NOT LIKE '%[^0-9 ]%'    
       AND Name NOT LIKE '%[0-9]% %[0-9]%'
```